# Adding self to static list in constructor

Tags: java

I basically want to add the instance of an object, inside of it's own constructor, to a list. I've tried the *this* keyword but still nothing.

You'll find the problem in the middle. It's "alarms.add(this); // TODO: This is the problem."

Thanks in advance! Below is the related code.

```
package com.brandonmxb.bpi;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import com.sun.media.sound.JavaSoundAudioClip;

public class Alarm extends Thread {
    private String tAlarm = null;
    private boolean enabled = true; // thread for alarm running
    private boolean alarm = false; // thread for alarm going off
    private String desc = "";

    private SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd kk:mm:ss z yyyy");
    private static SimpleDateFormat nt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");

    private static List<Alarm> alarms = new ArrayList<Alarm>(); // global list of all alarms, only one
    private static Settings saved; // alarm Settings file

    public void run(){ // always running, separate thread
        //System.out.println("Running Alarm thread...");
        String nTime = null;
        String nAlarm = null;

        while(enabled){ // always run and wait
            //nTime = df2.parse().toString();
            try {
                nAlarm = this.tAlarm.replace("XX", String.valueOf(Clock.getDateDay())); // replace with current day of month
                String s = Clock.getTime().toString();

                nTime = nt.format(ft.parse(s));

                //System.out.println(nTime + "=" + nAlarm); //debug

                if(nTime.equals(nAlarm)) // is it alarm time?
                    sound();
            } catch (ParseException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        //Log.makeLog(0, "Alarm completely disabled!");
    }

    public Alarm(String date, String desc, boolean save){ // set up alarm
        this.tAlarm = date; // set local alarm time
        this.desc = desc; // set description for obj alarm

        alarms.add(this); // TODO: This is the problem.

        if(save){
            saved.add(this.tAlarm, this.desc); // adds alarm to file
            saved.save();
        }
        this.start(); // start alarm clock threading
    }

    public Alarm(){ // called once upon init to LOAD alarms
        // load alarms from settings
        saved = new Settings("alarms.txt"); // makes new Setting class, 
        alarms.clear(); // should be empty, but clears anyway

        for(int i = 0; i < saved.size(); i++){
            String date = saved.getOpt(i);
            System.out.println("Opt: " + date);
            String desc = saved.get(saved.getOpt(i));
            System.out.println("Val: " + desc);

            alarms.add(new Alarm(date, desc, false)); 
        }
        Log.makeLog(0, "Alarm clock system loaded and initialized.");
    }

    public static void remove(int index){
        alarms.remove(index); // removes from alarms list
        saved.removeOpt(index); // removes from save file
        saved.save(); // save to file
    }

    public void sound(){ // make loud sound and alert as alarm
        Log.makeLog(0, "Alarm at " + tAlarm + " is about to go off.");
        Speak.Speak("Alarm: " + this.desc);

        alarm = true; // alarm is going off!
        while(alarm){ // alarm sounding off!
            try {
                new JavaSoundAudioClip(new FileInputStream(new File("res/tone.wav"))).play();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        Log.makeLog(0, "Alarm sound ended!");
    }

    public static List<Alarm> list(){ // return list of all added alarms
        return alarms;
    }

    public String getTime(){ // return alarm's time
        return tAlarm;
    }

    public String getDesc(){ // returns description of alarm
        return desc;
    }

    public boolean getAlarm(){ // returns if alarm is sounding
        return alarm;
    }

    public void setOff(){
        alarm = false; // disable current alarm sounding off
    }

    public void disable(){
        enabled = false;
        Log.makeLog(0, "Alarm '" + desc + "' disabled!");
    }
}
```

**EDITED:**
Thanks everyone for the input! All amazing answers and ideas but I think I might have been over complicating it. I think I'm just gonna go the simple route of @sayed.jalil.

```
(Main class)
Alarm a = new Alarm(Date, Desc, true); // make new alarm with date and description
Alarm.add(a); // adds to static list

(Alarm class, where the prob was)
public Alarm(String date, String desc, boolean save){ // set up alarm
    this.tAlarm = date; // set local alarm time
    this.desc = desc; // set description for obj alarm
    ... nothing here really.

(Alarm class, new add to list function)
public static void add(Alarm a){
    alarms.add(a); // important part
}
```

Comment: you really need to provide a short self contained correct example. See sscce.org for example.

Comment: I'm just guessing because your code is not enough to replicate the error, but just in case try this: synchronize your List of Alarms, use `private static List<Alarm> alarms = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Alarm>())`, as you're using Threads I suspect you have a race condition

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: @michaelanderson Sorry about that. Didn't want to get too over complicated. Basically I have one initial call to new Alarm(); that would set up all the basic things the class needs. Then later called would include the new Alarm(date, desc, true);

Comment: @morgano Is what you're saying, that calling alarms.add(this) should work if I try that? Interesting. One second.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the input! All amazing answers and ideas but I think I might have been over complicating it. I think I'm just gonna go the simple route of @sayed.jalil.
(Main class)
Alarm a = new Alarm(Date, Desc, true); // make new alarm with date and description
Alarm.add(a); // adds to static list
(Alarm class, where the prob was)
public Alarm(String date, String desc, boolean save){ // set up alarm
this.tAlarm = date; // set local alarm time
this.desc = desc; // set description for obj alarm
...
(Alarm class, new add to list function)
public static void add(Alarm a){
alarms.add(a);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the alarms.add line from the constructor. Define a new static function, pass it an alarm object as a parameter. e.g you could do something like this:

```
    public void createAlarm(){
        Alarm al = new Alarm();
        Alarm.insertAlarm(al);
    }

    public static insertAlarm(Alarm al){
        alarms.add(al);
    }
```

This will do it for you but you should not have a list of alarm objects in alarm class.

Comment: I thought of this but I wanted to be able to do it in the constructor.  I think you're right though. I'll just have to add the second line before the call of the alarm. Thanks for the help!

Comment: "...you should not have a list of alarm objects in alarm class." - why not?  Adding a createAlarm() method is reasonable if it needs to be called from outside the class, but regardless, having a List<Alarm> as a static member is perfectly fine if it makes the code more readable / maintainable.  It's all about context after all.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a design problem. Why you would like to have a *list of alarms* in the `Alarm` class?. That class should be supposed to represent *one* single alarm.

You could try creating another class, for example `AlarmList` (I'm not good with names), and there, you can store the `Alarm` instances.

Comment: Hmmmm... You're probably right. Dang. I wanted to keep all of it in one class. Having one initial call to new Alarm(); that would set up all the basic things the class needs. I just really wanted to be able to add the self instance of the object into the static list inside the constructor itself. I'll probably just do what sayed.jalil suggested and just have a second line before the object initialization. Thanks for the help. Mucho appreciato!

Comment: No, there's no reason you can't have a static List<Foo> inside the Foo class.  Does it make your design more readable / maintainable to do it that way?  If yes, then go for it.  If no, find a more intuitive design.  But there's nothing *per se* wrong with it under all circumstances.  What matters is readability / maintainability.

Comment: I think dividing your class in multiplate -more intuitive- classes would be the best approach. *Divide and Conquer!*

Comment: I like the idea of having my static list inside my regular class of objects, and all the objects (alarms) are on that list, waiting to be removed or more added.

Answer (score 1):

With the code condensed:

```
public Alarm(String date, String desc, boolean save){
    alarms.add(this);
}

public Alarm(){
    for(int i = 0; i < saved.size(); i++){
        // alarms.add !!
        //     v
        alarms.add(new Alarm(date, desc, false));
    }
}
```

You are adding the `new Alarm` to the list twice. The `new` statement is nested within a call to `add` and it also proceeds to add itself a second time in its constructor. If this is the problem you are talking about, you should just remove one of the adds.

Note that I'm also alarmed by your use of the no-arg constructor to `clear` the list, read settings, create new instances, etc. You should not be using constructors to do this kind of static initialization logic. Instead, refactor the initialization logic to a `static void` method or `static { }` initializer block.

Comment: The method (with parameters) you have there is used manually. When the user wants to add an alarm to the list and in turn, will be added to an alarms.txt file (not really included in my example). The method without parameters is just my initialization method called ONCE upon the program starting. It retrieves all the alarms from the file and adds them to the list. I'm not having a problem with that. :)

Comment: Are you suggesting that I just have an init() function for the Alarms class instead of an entire constructor? Probably would be better.

Comment: @BrandonMXB The 'method without parameters' is a constructor and yes that's what I'm suggesting. It should be moved to a method or static initialization block. Otherwise you are creating a Thread object when you call it and it's also a very vague functionality.

Comment: Sorry man. It's late. I'll be turning that constructor into some type of initialization function. It's just a class in a big project I'm working on. It could use some work around the edges. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

I don't follow what the problem is?  What are you trying to achieve which is failing?  "But still nothing" is unclear.

If I add a main() method to your class I find the Alarm instance correctly inserted in your static List:

> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>   Alarm alarm = new Alarm("date", "desc", false);
>   System.out.println("alarms.size(): " + alarms.size());
> }
> ```

Output: "alarms.size(): 1".

Is there some other result you're expecting?

Comment: I wanted to add the instance of an alarm into a static list from the constructor. But it doesn't add correctly. The best solution I've found so far is something like: code Alarm a = new Alarm(tAlarm, dAlarm, true); alarms.add(a); // but instead using a public function

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't add correctly?"  As I showed above, it adds fine when I do it.

Comment: Without the alarms.add(this); I get the proper alarms displayed, with it, I get double the alarms. It's kinda weird. (They're being pulled from a regular text file, and it's display in debug mode so you can understand.) Without the alarm.add(this): http://pastebin.com/mRqJnmz8 With: http://pastebin.com/QbQnKBDc

Comment: Notice it's adding double.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, in fact I can't (rank..)... I appreciate your help... I swear lol.

Comment: I knew that.  :-)  It's one of the others with the dogmatic opinions about static members.  Good luck!

Comment: @MarkPhillips The downvote is probably because ['Works for me' answers aren't considered good.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118992/are-works-for-me-answers-valid)

Comment: @Radiodef, perhaps my answer would have been more appropriate as a comment than an answer?  Fair enough.  Thanks!

Comment: @Radiodeg I kinda agree. When he said that, though with good intention and I really appreciated the help, I was kinda left confused like... Uh... Haha. Either way, problem solved. Thanks everyone!